# library importing issues in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, pylint

> import errors in python in  vs code

"i tried some imports for a chat bot project in vs code but its always shows some errors that shown in the picture below.
looking for solutions ,thank you."

[this picture shows the error that i seen after importing some libraries in python using vs code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTUke.png)

**picture**

> looking for solutions ,thank you.

Comment: Have you installed those libraries?

Comment: yes i installed and  its working well in jupyter notebook

Comment: did you choose the right interpreter?

Comment: @gogulcv Could you try using the terminal for running the script and let me know ?

Comment: @luigigi thank you. I have chosen the wrong interpreter.thanks man for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't selected the right interpreter.

1) Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)

2) Search for "Select Interpreter"

3) Select the installed python directory

Ref:- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-an-environment